# Symfony 2 Custom Constraints

Tags: validation, symfony

I am reading a **[tutorial](http://www.michelsalib.com/2011/04/create-your-own-constraint-validator-in-symfony2-a-doctrine-unique-validator/)** and there are some parts I dont understand:

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return 'validator.unique';
}
```

Is this a good practice or should I just use Symfony's default of `get_class($this).'Validator'` (from [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html))

```
public function requiredOptions()
{
    return array('entity', 'property');
}

public function targets()
{
    return self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT;
}
```

Are the above methods required? It doesn't appear in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

```
# MyApp/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    my.validator.unique.class:      MyApp\MyBundle\Validator\UniqueValidator

services:
    my.validator.unique:
       class:      %my.validator.unique.class%
       arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
       tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: validator.unique }
```

is that parameter declaration simply so that I can use `%my.validator.unique.class%`, instead of the fully qualified class name?

About the `name` & `alias`. Am I right to say `name` is the "type" of constraint. `alias` is the alias used by `Constraint::validatedBy()`

```
# Extension class
public function getAlias() {
    return 'my';
}
```

Is the above required? I dont see `my` used anywhere?

```
// get the existing registered namespaces for validator annotations
$namespaces = $container->getParameter('validator.annotations.namespaces');
// add our namespace under the alias myvalidation
$namespaces['myvalidation'] = 'MyApp\\MyBundle\\Validator\\';
// save it
$container->setParameter('validator.annotations.namespaces', $namespaces);
```

It seems just `@Annotation` in the `Constraint` class works? `validator.annotations.namespaces` gives an error about non-existant param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the `->validatedBy()` method, returning a simple class name will work only if your validator class does not have any dependency because the validator will try to create it using something as simple as `new $classname()`. The only problem (if it's really a problem...) with use of the service name is that you couple your constraint to the FrameworkBundle.

The `->getRequiredOptions()` method is empty by default so if you have any required option, it's a good practice too override this method.

The `->getTargets()` method already defaults to `self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT`. You should override it only if you want your constraint to work on the whole class `self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT` (you can even return an array if you want your constraint to work on both cases).

In your service definition, you made the choice of using the `%my.validator.unique.class% parameter to store the class name for the`my.validator.unique` service.

About the `->getName()` method, it's part of the `Extension` interface. If you decide to add some options under the `my` key of the `app/config/config.yml`, they will be passed as first argument of the `->load()` method.

The `name` of the tag will be used by the FrameworkBundle to find all the constraint validator services and register them into the `ConstraintValidatorFactory` (the part that is responsible of returning the right validator for a given constraint). The `alias`must be the same string as the one returned by the `->validatedBy()` method.

And you're right, the namespace registration stuff is not necessary.